# How much time it will take to resend code to phone? Firebase Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am implementing phone authentication (that firebase provides). Once user enters his **phonenumber**, firebase send a verification code to that phone number.

But sometimes code does not receive on mobile, so i want to add option to resend code.

In that case firebase do not allows you to resend code instantly, it will take sometime before you can resend code. Else it will give error:

> POST
>   https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/sendVerificationCode?key=AIxxxxDtg4xxxxxxxxxxxEhxxxxqpxxxxxxXI
>   400 ()

I have added timeinterval of **60s** before resend button is enabled, but that is not the time google required.

It a little more may be **80-90** seconds.**I have read the docs, but could not find anything about it.**

Can anyone enlighten me about this? How much time it will take to resend code?

For "**formality**" here is my code:

```
var appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
    fire.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(refinedNumber, appVerifier)
    .then(function (confirmationResult) {
      thisclass.setState({
        btnLoading: '',
        page: 'code'
      })
      var timeleft = 60;
      setInterval(function(){
        if (timeleft > 0) {
          timeleft--;
          thisclass.setState({
            resendTime: 'Resend Code In '+timeleft+'s'
          })
        }else{
          thisclass.setState({
            resendTime: '',
            resendEnabled: ''
          })
        }

      }, 1000)
      // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
      window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
    }).catch(function (error) {
      // Error; SMS not sent
      // ...
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a specific period of time to wait to resend the code. However due to delays in delivery, it is recommended to wait before resending the code. 
FirebaseUI-web waits 15 seconds before resending the code:

https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/blob/master/javascript/widgets/handler/phonesigninstart.js#L176

This is also important as there is a limit to how many times a code is sent to the same phone number to prevent possible abuse.

Comment: What happens if you try to resend before 120s?

Comment: It let me send. But not before 120s. and 120s is too much.